# Iterate through JSON objects with jq in shell script

Tags: json, shell, jq

I'm trying to parse a json file in a shell script program, using jq.

The JSON structure looks something like this:

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "playlists":[
            {
               "title":"Level One Title",
               "courses":[
                  {
                     "title":"Level One Course One Title",
                     "lessons":[
                        {
                           "title":"lesson 1 title",
                           "url":"lesson 1 url"
                        },
                        {
                           "title":"lesson 2 title",
                           "url":"lesson 2 url"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "title":"Level One Course Two Title",
                     "lessons":[
                        {
                           "title":"lesson 1 title",
                           "url":"lesson 1 url"
                        },
                        {
                           "title":"lesson 2 title",
                           "url":"lesson 2 url"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "title":"Level Two Title",
               "courses":[
                  {
                     "title":"Level Two Course One Title",
                     "lessons":[
                        {
                           "title":"lesson 1 title",
                           "url":"lesson 1 url"
                        },
                        {
                           "title":"lesson 2 title",
                           "url":"lesson 2 url"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "title":"Level Two Course Two Title",
                     "lessons":[
                        {
                           "title":"lesson 1 title",
                           "url":"lesson 1 url"
                        },
                        {
                           "title":"lesson 2 title",
                           "url":"lesson 2 url"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Since I'm an iOS developer, I have written a mock piece of Swift code which would achieve what I want. It looks like this:

```
for level in levels {
    let title = level["title"]
    //TODO: create a folder with title and set as pwd
    for course in level["courses"] {
        let courseTitle = course["title"]
        //TODO: create a folder with title and set as pwd
        for lesson in course["lessons"] {
            let title = lesson["title"]
            let videoURL = lesson["url"]
            //TODO: download video in current folder with title
        }
    }
}
```

`levels` is an `Array` of `Dictionaries`, `level` is one of those `Dictionaries`. Each level contains an `Array` of `courses`, each of which is a `Dictionary`, containing an `Array` of `lesson` dictionaries.

Coming from Swift, I found jq's syntax quite confusing, especially assigning function return values to variables. Here is how far I've gotten:

```
levels=$(jq ".items[0].playlists" data.json)
for level in $levels
do
    title=$($level | jq ".title")
    echo $title
done
```

This doesn't seem to work at all. I guess my logic to use for-loops is totally wrong here. Any ideas how this is done?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide sample input and sample output, so folks don't need to read through your code. Also, there's context that's hard to make out from the code (is the top-level `levels` a list or a dictionary, for example?)

Comment: BTW, in general, you should be calling `jq` just once with a program that does all the iteration -- which is to say that the loops should be in the jq code, not the shell script.

Comment: (and `for level in $levels` is buggy as shell -- see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Right you are, @CharlesDuffy. I have expanded my question with more info.

Comment: An example would be more helpful -- that way one can copy-and-paste your given input and validate that their code works with it, rather than trying to read your spec and build input therefrom.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post the JSON itself because of NDA reasons.

Comment: We don't want live data (that would be covered by NDA); what we want is a [mcve]. "Minimal" generally calls for simplifying from whatever your real-world use case was, generating the simplest possible case that demonstrates the same challenge.

Comment: OK, I will add a sample JSON structure to the question ASAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code to extract the titles and URLs into distinct shell variables may look like:

```
jq_program='
.items[].playlists[]            # we only care about playlist contents
| .title as $level_title        # store the level title before recursing
| .courses[]                    # ...into elements of the array in .courses...
| .title as $course_title       # repeat to store the course title
| .lessons[]                    # ...before recursing into the lesson...
# ...and emitting the stored level and course titles, plus the lesson title and url
| [$level_title, $course_title, .title, .url] | @tsv                              
'

while IFS=$'\t' read -r level_title course_title lesson_title lesson_url <&3; do
  mkdir -p -- "$level_title/$course_title"
  ## For test purposes, just store the URL in the file
  printf '%s\n' "$lesson_url" >"$level_title/$course_title/$lesson_title"
  ## If we had real data, we might instead be running something like:
  # curl -o "$level_title/$course_title/$lesson_title" "$lesson_url"
done 3< <(jq -r "$jq_program" <input.json)
```

Here, we have `jq` doing the work of recursing and emitting a flat (tab-separated) list, and are reading that list in bash. For obvious reasons, this only works if content can't contain tabs; if you need to work with arbitrary strings (within the range that bash can store), it's possible to generate NUL-delimited output from `jq`, but requires one of the workarounds discussed in [stedolan/jq#1271](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1271).

See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) discussing the technique we're using here to read tab-separated data in from the output of `jq`.

Comment: You are missing the "lessons" layer in each course. Also, I don't need the names in a list, I need to create a folder structure similar to the JSON.

Comment: @damjandd, see the `mkdir` in the shell script? It's creating the directory structure from the JSON, reading from the list emitted by jq, and the `curl` is downloading into that directory.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry, I missed that.

Comment: @damjandd, ...generally speaking, StackOverflow is here to be a teaching resource, not to build your exact code for you to spec. We're well within our rights, for that matter, to close your question as overbroad insofar as it goes beyond the minimum necessary complexity to demonstrate a technical question in a manner reusable by others.

Comment: @damjandd, okay -- as-edited, this appears to test out correctly with your new data; I get `Level One Title/Level One Course One Title/lesson 2 title` created containing `lesson 2 url`, for example (with the `echo` as a standin for `curl`).

Comment: Great! So for the download, I could actually just replace the echo command with a ffmpeg command which is needed to download my actual file, right?

Comment: ...so you're transcoding it at the same time, not just downloading? But anyhow, yeah, replace it with whatever's appropriate.

Comment: Are you sure the last line is correct? I'm getting an error saying: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Comment: It's correct if your shell is really bash (or ksh). Any chance you might be running with `sh`?

Comment: Yes, I was running with sh. Works like a charm with bash!

Comment: ...see [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) to understand that idiom. If that's a bug you're willing to live with, you can pipe from `jq` into the loop instead, and that'll be compatible with baseline POSIX.